# Algorithm for path in an undirected graph between 2 points

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, undirected-graph

Suppose we have an undirected graph, and two nodes A and B. I need to write a method to find a path without cycles between A and B. All edges of this graph have the same weight. The method must terminate as soon as it finds such a path. How can I implement this?

Comment: Research Dijkstra's Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm), which can also be implemented as an instance of A-star (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) with a constant heuristic of 0.

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: @Noctis: I'm not a student

Comment: your question is vague, on a topic that is fairly known, you didn't say what's your problem, and you just ask for a solution. This is not the site for that. Seems that @Margus gave an answer nevertheless :).

Comment: Is this a directed or undirected graph?

Comment: @johnnyRose: undirected

Comment: You use Dijkstra.  First you must build the graph.  The mark all visited nodes as false. The try every path until you find 1st successful path.  As you move through the graph mark visited nodes so you don't go back to a node already tested.  You are not asking for shortest path just the first path you find.

Comment: Could you **post** what have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Without major limitations you can visit the graph as you like. 2 most common are:
[image]

For more help i advice you try someting and show some effort on your part.

Comment: This is a binary tree, not a directed/undirected graph. There are similarities, but perhaps a different diagram would be beneficial.

Comment: It is a tree and 2 search techniques. Graph does not have costs and have no cycles therefore visiting the graph simplifies to a tree. Hope you understand now.

Comment: The question never stated the **graph** couldn't have cycles. The question states the final **path** between points A and B had to be acyclic.

Answer (score 0):

You can find here an implementation of **[Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)** Algorithm to :

[Find The Shortest Path](http://www.maxburstein.com/blog/introduction-to-graph-theory-finding-shortest-path/)

Comment: Link-only answers are extremely discouraged. Please summarize an answer to the problem, and provide links for further learning.

Comment: I don't need to find the shortest path

Comment: @BORIS So?  You only specified that you needed *a* path.  The shortest path is definitely a path.  It's also pretty easy to find.

Comment: Dijkstra is an overkill for unweighted graph. Breadth first search would work just fine in this case and easier to implement.